# Prevent scroll to top --Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I am trying to prevent the page from scrolling to the top of the page when I click on an anchor.

I have done this many times before, but I am not understanding what I am missing this time.

Please have a look at this code:

```
$('#regionMapNav a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

        var i = $(this).attr("class");
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        if(i != 'active'){
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.map').hide();

                $('#' + name + 'Map').fadeIn(3000);
                return false;   
            }

});
```

thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
I went ahead and create a hack to just scroll to bottom since nothing that should work is working....I know it is not the best, but it works...Here is the code just in case someone ever has the same issue. Keep in mind that this item I am creating is at the bottom of the page. Also, that there is a dynamically loaded large header on this page. I think my issue has something to do with that, but I just don't have the energy today to trace back my mistake.

```
$('#regionMapNav a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

        var i = $(this).attr("class");
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        if(i != 'active'){
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.map').hide();

                $('#' + name + 'Map').fadeIn(3000);
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                return false;   
            }

});
```

Comment: Hmm... That looks like it should work. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I think the issue is that this page has a dynamically added header...I'm gonna just add a scroll to bottom handler as I know this should work.

Comment: What is the link's HREF? I've had some issues with browsers not respecting `preventDefault()` when the HREF was pointing to "#" and I was binding on the `click` event. Try setting the HREF to "".

Comment: Looks pretty good to me; also hard to reproduce without the markup. ;-) On initial inspection the only thing I see is that I don't think you need the return false at all (either in or out of the if statement). Is it possible that there's another plugin (some sort of "scroll to"?) that has a bound event kicking in?

Comment: Tried that also and it did not work. Good idea though. I posted a hack for that works for me since this map is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @mitch If the header is dynamically added, is it possible that it's just a timing issue? Is the rest of that function executing as well? (ie. maybe the click handler isn't being bound, period)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false;` outside of the if statement. It's probably scrolling to the top on links where i is not 'active'.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` should already be doing the job of preventing propagation and is usually recommended over returning false.

Comment: I agree with Greg, use event.preventDefault().  This will prevent the default actions of elements such as links and submit buttons.